# Is there a RN Number Picker working on android as a wheel?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, picker

I'm building a React Native app, and I want my user to input a number of player and I ant to to be intuitive, i want a weel instead of writing it with the keyboeard.

I've tried to use the basic Picker module as shown below :

```
export default function NumberPicker(props) {
    let pickerItemArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 23; i++){
      pickerItemArray.push(<Picker.Item label={""+i} value={i} key={i}/>);
    }

    return (
      <Picker {...props}>
        {pickerItemArray}
      </Picker>
    );
}
```

It works fine on iphone with a wheel of zero to 23 but this picker is not a wheel on android :(

Comment: Wheels aren't normally used on Android.  You can find a library that does it I'm sure, but it will make your app look like a bad iOS port rather than like an Android app.  Android users don't expect or want wheels.

Comment: Then what is the best input for a number ? the basic dialog is very ugly...

Comment: Generally an edit text in the main app.  You don't normally pop up a dialog to enter a number.